# JDBI Transactional .inTransaction() with void return type?

Tags: java, database, jdbi

A JDBI [Handle](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/Handle.html#inTransaction(org.skife.jdbi.v2.TransactionCallback)) allows for transactions to be run via a call to `.inTransaction(TransactionCallback<ReturnType> callback)`. This TransactionCallback may be a `VoidTransactionCallback`, which allows for a void return type.

I'm not seeing an equivalent when using a DAO that implements [Transactional](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/mixins/Transactional.html).

`Transactional` provides an `inTransaction(Transaction<ReturnType,SelfType> func)` method, where Transaction must have a return type. That return type can be `Void`, but is there another option I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `useTransaction`.

The typical method pattern is `withX` for methods with a return type, and `useX` for void return--`inTransaction` being the only exception.